# Irreducibility of a polynomial like $x^n-a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, field-theory

Let $x^n-a \in F[x]$, where $F$ is field, be an irreducible polynomial on $F$, I want to prove: for any $m|n$, the polynomial $x^m-a$ is also irreducible on $F$. Any help is welcomed. Thanks all.

Comment: Hint:  if $x^m-a=p(x)q(x)$  then $x^{md}-a=p(x^d)q(x^d)$.

Comment: So, $x^n-a=p(x^{n/m})q(x^{n/m})$ will be reducible. But this is so easy!